# Mapa con trazado ruta en una consulta

Tags: php, mysql

Buen dia, quisiera saber si es posbile mostrar un mapa con una ruta, mi empresa es de transporte publico y quisiera que cuando se consulta muestre la ruta con puntos de salida y destion pero la cuestion es que las direcciones estan en la base de datos, estoy usando netamente mysql y php para el backend y desearia que me puedan colaborar.
he buscado mucha informacion por internet pero no he encontrado nada concreto al respecto...Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]  tienes una lectura obligatoria [ask] antesde publicar una pregunta.

Comment: Buenas, Yostin. La respuesta es sí, seguro que se puede. Pero si no nos indicas la estructura básica de tus tablas en la base de datos, qué información quieres extraer de ellas y qué has intentado hasta ahora, poco podemos ayudarte.

Comment: hay muchisima mas informacion en api de google maps, pero por ahora con la poca informacion podria decirte que necesitas un campo en la base para guardar las coordenadas del punto en la direccion, consultas la api y te muestre las coordenadas para poder ir dibujando en el mapa a mostrar la ruta, es la forma mas facil de hacerlo.  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50843/como-construir-una-ruta-con-la-api-maps-de-google